# Solving an cubic equation

Tags: quadratics

This comes from a chemistry question but it is the maths I am struggling with. I solved the determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix to get:

$$(a-E)^3 - 3B^2(a-E) + 2B^3 = 0$$

I need to solve this in terms of $a$ and $B$. So for example $E = a + 2B$.

If you break it down into brackets, (.....)(.....) then I would be able to see how to make it zero as if one bracket equals zero the whole equation will. However I am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: "Breaking down into brackets" is what is referenced to as "factorizing a polynomial".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=a-E$ then

$$(a-E)^3 - 3B^2(a-E) + 2B^3 = 0 \iff x^3-3B^2x+2B^3=0$$

and

$$x^3-3B^2x+2B^3=x^3-B^2x-2B^2x+2B^3=x(x-B)(x+B)-2B(x-B)=(x-B)(x^2+xB-2B)=(x-B)(x-B)(x+2B)=(x-B)^2(x+2B)=0$$

thus

- $x-B=0\implies E=a-B$
- $x+2B=0\implies E=a+2B$

Comment: The transformation $x = a - E$ is a useful simplification, but since cubics (other than sum/difference of cubes) is not a standard school factorization topic, it would probably be helpful to remind the OP that the factorization can be discovered by the precalculus [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). In this case, the trials for $p/q$ are divisors of $2B^3$ divided by divisors of $1,$ and thus are $\pm 2B^3,$ $\pm B^3,$ $\pm 2B^2,$ $\pm B^2,$ etc. *(moments later)* While I was writing this, you provided an alternate way of obtaining the factorization.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You are completely right, thanks for the pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

your equation can be factorized  into $$(a+2 B-x) (-a+B+x)^2=0$$
i have changed the $E$ to $x$